# How to configure Rollup for a React application?

Tags: reactjs, rollupjs

I've got two other applications that are working just fine with Rollup & React but this time around even this - a very simple example is not working.

Not sure what I'm missing but this set up throws `Uncaught Reference: React is not defined`

**rollup.config.js:**

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import serve from 'rollup-plugin-serve';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';

export default {
  input: './index.js',
  output: {
    file: './build/index.js',
    format: 'iife',
    globals: {
      react: 'React',
      'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    babel(),
    commonjs(),
    serve({
      contentBase: '',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: '8000',
    }),
    livereload(),
  ],
  external: [
    'react',
    'react-dom',
  ],
};
```

**.babelrc:**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "private": true,
  "description": "xxx",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "test": "echo No tests specified"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "xxx"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.6.3",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "rollup": "^1.23.1",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.3.3",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^1.0.4",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^2.0.3",
    "rollup-plugin-serve": "^1.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-svg": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^5.1.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "xxx": "^0.1.0",
    "xxx": "^0.1.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react-easy-state": "^6.1.3",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.88.1"
  }
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>blah</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="test-app"></div>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="./build/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const Thing = () => {
  return <div>Hi</div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Thing />, document.getElementById('test-app'));
```

What am I doing wrong? I get the feeling it is something **exceedingly** simple. Please let me know if I could add anymore details that may help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me was including the package `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'`

In the `rollup.config.js` add the lines;

```
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
export default {
  ...
  plugins: [
    ...
    nodeResolve({
      extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
    }),
  ]
}
```